# Possibility of no solution in Ethhash

Tags: mining, difficulty

Referring to http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf, especially Appendix J on Ethhash PoW algorithm

It's stated that the nonce is a 64-bit number. The output is a 256-bit number, and it will be compared against

2^256 / (difficulty level)

Is there a possibility that all values of the nonce would not produce a satisfiable output that is within the target range?